# Where are the Ubuntu images for ARM?

Tags: system-installation, iso, arm

I can't find ARM images for the latest Ubuntu release for an ARMv7 device at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com .

In [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) there is a link that doesn't work anymore and there is a suggestion to switch to Ubuntu Touch, but I'm not interested in Ubuntu Touch. I want Ubuntu on my ARM device, otherwise I will switch to other GNU/Linux distributions.

Is the support for ARM discontinued?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ubuntu for ARM Images are here:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm

Comment: It would help if you were to mention what piece of hardware you are trying to run ubuntu on.

Comment: Nexus 7 2013 - codename flo

Comment: Ok now I'm confused. Ubuntu Touch _is_ Ubuntu.

Comment: the problem is the interface and the environment, it's useless to me, I would like to have desktop apps.

Comment: Desktop apps won't really run well, they're not designed for touch; in 14.10 and onwards they will start to share applications.

Comment: @user2485710 asked about official desktop images at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042696/are-there-official-ubuntu-arm-aarch64-desktop-images