# Are there official Ubuntu ARM / aarch64 desktop images?

Tags: arm

I could only find server ARM images at: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

But are there any ARM images that come with a graphical desktop installed by default?

I don't have specific hardware requirements, even just running it on QEMU would be fine for now.

Comment: Graphical desktops do not work well on ARM devices, because there is usually no appropriate graphics driver available. Without it, graphical programs either won't work at all, or would be painfully slow.

Comment: @mikewhatever what about Raspberry Pi 3 for example? Looks good enough: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKv5YGi0Njw

Comment: Indeed, there are a few exceptions like RP3 and Odroid devices with stable graphics, but even those have limited RAM and week CPUs, which make them more suitable as servers. Needless to say, you could always try and install a light DE, for example Lubuntu or MATE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/952885/installing-a-graphic-user-interface-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @K7AAY disagree with duplicate because this is focused on images with pre-installed graphical interface.

Answer (score 24):

Yes there are. You can find the installer images for Ubuntu Desktop on arm64 in the daily builds:

- 22.04 LTS: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/

*Note that these images are **not officially supported**. They should be stable, however, and they are created by the Ubuntu project*

Comment: Nice, seems to be  the first LTS with ARM desktop by comparing with https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/bionic/daily-live/current/

Comment: but will this work with the mac m1?

Comment: These images work on the M1 mac using a [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/nl/) VM.

Answer (score 12):

Installing Ubuntu Desktop for arm64 using Ubuntu Server ISO

At the end of the installation, you will have Ubuntu Server installed without any GUI. To install Ubuntu Desktop, log in and run:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: But what is your starting point system? :-)

Comment: it reads "Ubuntu Server". I guess you can install the ARM version of server, and then download the desktop packages from there.

Comment: only solution for ubuntu 20.04 thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in the ubuntu daily build

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: I can't see an ARM build in the link.